# Please update minimal understanding close reason verbiage

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

"why they didn't work".

That's a stupid phrase. You don't know why it didn't work. How about "and what error you got" or "and what you expected to happen".

If folks knew why it didn't work, 90% of them wouldn't come here.

Comment: While I believe that most people don't take that phrase literally - understanding full well that "why" actually means "specifically how" -  I'd love to know what objection the down-voters have against making this phrase less ambiguous.

Comment: You're talking about developers. We're often a pedantic lot. :p (really doesn't make us right, just pedantic)

Comment: Not as pedantic as DBAs.

Comment: May not worth the effort to change this.  [Shog has stated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215041/182513) that this close reason will be going away, presumably in favor of something worded a lot better with less overlap

Comment: @psubsee2003 ah very cool, was not aware of that one.

Comment: @AaronBertrand My DBA isn't pedantic at all... But my sample size of 1 probably isn't reliable.

Comment: @Cruncher considering he's a dba.se mod, he's probably making a private joke ;-)